# Align button vertically center in MaterialUI grid

Tags: css, material-ui

I would to like align the button vertically center within this grid. I have tried vertical-align but there is no effect. I am able to adjust the vertical position of the button using `top: "30%"` but I don't think that is the best way to center the button.

[image]

```
<form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
  <Grid container spacing={1}>
    <Grid item xs={5}>
      <TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="AWS account"
        className={classes.textField}
        margin="normal"
      />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={7}>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
        Link AWS account
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</form>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need [Grid API](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/) . Prop `alignItems` with `center` value. Read about `flexbox` in CSS and always check the docs first.